# How do I rearrange a string after splitting it in java?

Tags: java, string

I want to rearrange a name being put in `lastname:firstname,middlename` so that the o/p is first middle and last. I have it so it splits at the semicolon comma and space.

This is what I have so far:

```
Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Welcome to the Name Rearranging Program");
System.out.println(" Enter a name in our format:");
// format is lastname:firstname,middlename

String name = n.next();

String[] arr = name.split("[:, ]");

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Well you know `arr.length` should be 3, so why not output each name individually?

Comment: I don't see the problem with this code fragment, besides printing some spaces (`System.out.print(' ');`) this could should work fine...

Comment: When I did that it would output everything up to where it was split so it didn´t work.

Comment: @CommuSoft - No the whole point is to move the surname from first position to last position.

Comment: It works it just doesn´t print it in the order I want- first middle last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this sounds like homework or another learning exercise, here's a hint to get you on your way.  Try adding the following...

```
String arr = name.split(...);
String last = arr[0];
String first = arr[1];
String middle = arr[2];
```

This should be enough to make the next step as intuitive as possible.

Comment: But I need it to split at a colon then a comma and then a space?

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess I will follow atk's lead and not give away the answer completely but you could also do this using strings rather than arrays. You can do something along these lines:

```
int colon = name.indexOf(":");
int comma = name.indexOf(",");
```

From there you can just use `string.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` with the two above variables to separate each part of the name into its own String and print it out however you wish.

This link talks about substring:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm